# CodeCov is ignoring certain files. No settings for ignore in YAML. Python/Django

Tags: python, django, codecov

I have a `Python` `Django` project on `GitHub` and I'm using `CodeCov` with this project.

I have two apps in this `Django` project, a general app, and a general_api app. For some reason, all of the changes made in the general_api app files are being ignored.

I had `YAML` settings like this to ignore my test cases:

```
codecov:
  require_ci_to_pass: false
ignore:
- (?s:test_[^\/]+\.py.*)\Z
- (?s:tests_[^\/]+\.py.*)\Z
- ^test.py.*
- ^tests.py.*
```

However, I've removed them with the same issue.

Is there some other way to ignore, or set the ignore parameters in `CodeCov` other than the `YAML` settings?

Comment: Tom from Codecov here. Unfortunately there isn't another way ignore files. 

I'm guessing that your directory structure looks like this

```
.
├── general
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   └── tests
│       └── test.py
├── general_api
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   └── tests
│       └── test.py
```

What I'm not sure is what files you are trying to ignore, and what files are currently being ignored.

Comment: Actually, @ThomasHu, I think I just figured it out. It seems that the issue is actually with how the coverage package checks. It only seems to check across files that have some sort of test case interaction. If a file is written and no test cases are written for it and no test case actions use any of that code, it seems that the coverage report will not find it. This was not something I'd realized before. As soon as I added a test case to test one part of one of the ignored files, now all of them are showing as they're all interrelated. 

I'm going to add this as my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of my problems was actually in how I was using `coverage` to generate my coverage report.

I was previously using the command line: `coverage run -m pytest`

This only creates a coverage report on files that have test cases against them or files that are interacted with while testing. Files that have no interaction or test cases would be completely omitted.

I found through the `coverage` [documentation](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/6.3.2/source.html), that I needed to add `--source=.` to my command line if I wanted the coverage report to include untested files. This is now showing all files in my root source.

The final command was: `coverage run --source=. -m pytest`